# Issue in plotting points properly using Heatmap Canvas d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas

I am trying to plot the data. See the following images:
[image: input nd outut]
And also the second image:
[image: input and output]

The following is the code that I have tried to manipulte:

```
private updateCircles(container, points: Example2D[]) {
    
    let selection = container.selectAll("circle").data(points);
    selection.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 3);
    selection
      .attr({
          cx : (d: Example2D,i) => (i),
          cy : (d: Example2D) => this.yScale(d.x1),       
      })
      .style("fill", d => this.color(d.label));
  }
}
```

The yScale is defined as:

```
this.yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(yDomain)
      .range([height - 1 * padding, 0]);
```

the `yDomain = [-1,1]`

What I am looking for is that the data must get reflected the exact way as it is in the thumbnail.

Let me know what I am missing to improve.

Comment: You mean that graphs on right is what  you want? Or do you mean that graphs on right are the ones that are currently being made by you?

Comment: I wanted to have the graph on Right get reflected on the left. Say if the value is one on top, zeroes in middle and -1 's at bottom. You know the scaling thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

> your tumbnail have differend height and width with new image

You get the data by doing

```
container.selectAll("circle").data(points);
```

Append it on selection by

```
selection.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 3);
```

*but your svg container (width and height) on tumbnail and new image is different*

Please try reformat the scale :

```
private updateCircles(container, points: Example2D[]) {

    //get data
    let selection = container.selectAll("circle").data(points);
    // this is new image on the right width and hight
    let rangeX = [ ] //find width [min,max] of your new image on the right
    let rangeY = [ ] //find height [min,max] of your new image on the right

    //try set new scale
    let newxScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(xDomain)
      .range(rangeX);
    let newyScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(yDomain)
      .range(rangeY);

    //append with new scale
    selection.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 3);
    selection
      .attr({
          cx : (d: Example2D,i) => newxscale(i),
          cy : (d: Example2D) => newyscale(d.x1),       
      })
      .style("fill", d => this.color(d.label));
  }
}
```

If you want to reflect the data same as the thumbnail. make sure your scaleX and scaleY  is in the proper format.

Comment: Sure let me check it out I will let you know.

Comment: It is saying some ,(comma) issue. Can you help, what might be the issue? I thought and tried: changed this to `[new height min, new height max]` to `[new height.min, new height.max]`, then it started giving issue with the variable `xDomain`

Comment: I am not getting way how I can get the scaling to proper what I am willing to have. Please let me know if there a way out.